# Button in the layout is not showing

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm trying to place a button under an image view in the layout of the .xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name: " />

<LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/divider01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Meeting Point Position"
                android:paddingLeft="100dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="9dp"
                android:background="@drawable/t_505_12">
            </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/lat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="LAT: " />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/lng"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="LNG: " />

<LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/divider01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date/Time"
                android:paddingLeft="120dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="9dp"
                android:background="@drawable/t_505_12">
            </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Date: " />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Time: " />

<LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/divider01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Navigation Arrow"
                android:paddingLeft="120dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="9dp"
                android:background="@drawable/t_505_12">
            </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="90sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="190sp"       
    android:text="Navigate" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

But the problem is that: only the image view appears and the button is not showing.
Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: You are using 3 LinearLayouts ! That just isn't ment to be. Use just one LinearLayout and distribute views in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to put your code into `ScrollView`

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <!--   
           Here Goes your whole Layoout
        -->

  </ScrollView>
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Are they wrapped in a LinearLayout?

You can always set a drawable top of the Button via android:drawableTop attribute

Comment: Vertical layout is not the overall layout type.  That is a sub tag.

Comment: If your image is too big and your screen is small button can be invisible. You have a very big margin within the button. Can you paste your whole xml file please?

Answer (score 0):

Your ImageView might be forcing your button off of the screen.  How large is your image?  Could you try scaling the image size down and putting it back into the ImageView to see if your button appears then?  I assume you are using something like a LinearLayout.  If you are using a relative layout then I think you should place a layout_below tag or something similiar.  Also, you could try placing your Button above your ImageView in the xml file, so the image would then be below your button, if your button did not show up then, then there must be an alternate problem.

Comment: accoding to the design, the button should be below

Comment: please tell me how to set the size of the image